# Unable to click custom URL link

Tags: ios, swift, custom-url

I've created a link using `Custom URL Scheme`. I am sharing this link using native options like this:

```
func nativeSharing(sender: UIButton) {
        if let link = NSURL(string: "myappurl://") {
            let objectsToShare = ["", link] as [Any]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList]

            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
            self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

It works as expected, I'm getting Email with link

> myappurl://

But It is not clickable. What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: its the string `myappurl://` not the link, in here you need to append originalURL

Comment: I want to share link. Please can you tell me how to share it ?

Comment: I want to redirect to my app once user clicks link. What is possible way to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment because I don't have enough "reputation" but did you make sure you have the https:// before your link?

Also would you be able to show all the nonspecific parts of the link? the .com, http:// and all in case that's where the problem is.

Also if it were to be clickable what do you expect to happen? (trying to get a better sense of where the issue could be)

Comment: I want to redirect to app from this link. I didn't include https cause when i add https it doesn't work in safari.

Comment: But it does open, so maybe we have to figure out why your app is not opening from safari. What exactly is happening when you get to safari? Is it a page not found, has an "open" button, or redirects to another link?

Comment: when i use this link with https:// it shows web page is not available but it works fine with link which i have generated with custom url scheme inside my application. I followed these steps to generate link http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/ios-custom-url-schemes/

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is the difference between when it's working in your app and when it's not working.  

Also were you able to double check that when it's not working safari isn't changing the link?